# trying to add office-ui-fabric-react in a yo generated spfx webpart causes error on build

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling

I'm experiencing build errors when adding

```
 <TextField label='TextField with an icon' iconProps={ { iconName: 'Calendar' } } />
```

resulting with this error on gulp build

> Error - typescript -
>   node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\Image\Image.Props.d.ts(3,43):
>   error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member
>   'ImgHTMLAttributes'. Error - typescript -
>   node_modules\office-ui-fabric-react\lib\components\TextField\TextField.Props.d.ts(24,47): error TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member
>   'AllHTMLAttributes'. Error - 'typescript' sub task errored after 2.24
>   s  "TypeScript error(s) occurred."

I think it may be because of the typescript compiler which is in version 2.2.2

Anybody experiencing the same?

Comment: i have the same error today...

Comment: I could not find a solution..

Comment: Yes this seems to be the same issue logged on GitHub: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/765

Comment: Looking into it - Can you see what version of OUIFR is installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest OUIFR release is not compatible with SPFX at this point.  You should install version 4.28.0 of OUIFR.